# Pandas - Get Business Days between dates with a custom calendar?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to count the business days between two days using Pandas. However, this must be done considering the [Brazilian holidays](http://www.anbima.com.br/feriados/arqs/feriados_nacionais.xls).

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [custom-business-days](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days) . Follow the link to find more details.

> The CDay or CustomBusinessDay class provides a parametric BusinessDay class which can be used to create customized business day calendars which account for local holidays and local weekend conventions.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

 # Read holidays from excel, format them to dates, remove unwanted rows. 
holidayfile ='feriados_nacionais.xls'   
df_holiday = pd.read_excel(holidayfile)
df_holiday = df_holiday.convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')
df_holiday = df_holiday.dropna(subset=['Data'])

holidays=df_holiday['Data'].tolist()

bday_Brazil = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays)

dt = datetime.datetime(2017,10,10)
print (dt + bday_Brazil)
dt = datetime.datetime(2017,10,11)
print (dt + bday_Brazil)
dt = datetime.datetime(2017,10,12)
print (dt + bday_Brazil)
dt = datetime.datetime(2017,10,13)
print (dt + bday_Brazil)
```

Output

```
2017-10-11 00:00:00
2017-10-13 00:00:00
2017-10-13 00:00:00
2017-10-16 00:00:00
```

Now use [np.busday_count()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html#numpy.busday_count) and pass custom holidays

> holidays : array_like of datetime64[D], optional
>   An array of dates to consider as invalid dates. They may be specified in any order, and NaT (not-a-time) dates are ignored. This list is saved in a normalized form that is suited for fast calculations of valid days.

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    order_from  date_to
    2017-10-10  2017-10-16
    2017-04-09  2017-04-18
    2017-04-10  2017-04-20"""), header=1)
df.order_from = pd.to_datetime(df.order_from, infer_datetime_format=True)
df.date_to = pd.to_datetime(df.date_to, infer_datetime_format=True)

df['date_diff'] = np.busday_count(
    df.order_from.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
    df.date_to.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),holidays=holidays)
print (df)
```

output

```
  order_from    date_to  date_diff
0 2017-10-10 2017-10-16          3
1 2017-04-09 2017-04-18          5
2 2017-04-10 2017-04-20          7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the following error when trying to use  np.busday_count() with this holidays:

ValueError: Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an array of dates.

Is this because the dtype of dates in holidays is datetime64[ns]?

Comment: My bad, missed this part `holidays=df_holiday['Data'].tolist()`